# Choppy UIView animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation, quartz-core

I use a UIView animation to randomly animate 5 squares (UIButtons) around the screen. Depending on a user selection, there are anywhere from 2 to 5 squares visible. When only 2 are visible, the other three's hidden values get set to YES, so they are actually still animating (right?), they just aren't visible. But when only 2 are visible, the animation is smooth, but when all five are visible, the animation gets choppy. I'm not really sure how to describe it, because the squares are still moving at the correct speed and moving to the correct points; the choppiness isn't terrible, just bad enough to be noticeable. Is there any way to get rid of it? This is the code I use to animate the squares:

Edit: changed animations to block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationSpeed 
                              delay:0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                         animations:^{
                             view.center = destPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if([view isEqual:squareThree])
                                 [self moveBadGuys];
                         }
         ];

/*for(UIButton* button in squareArray) {
    if(!shouldMove)
        return;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"b" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationSpeed];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    view.center = destPoint;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}*/
```

Edit: the view presenting this is the third in a stack of three UIViewController presented with

```
ViewController* controller = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Does this way of presenting views eat up memory?

Comment: Could it be because you are low in memory?

Comment: I was think that, and I don't know all that much about how much memory an iPhone has to work with or how much creating a single IBOutlet drains your resources, but I do have quite a few IBOutlets in that View Controller

Comment: No that way of presenting views isn't eating up memory. Instead of a for statement try just doing one animation at a time and see if the choppiness still occurs.

Comment: Yeah, that stopped the choppiness, which doesn't make sense to me because even when only two squares are moving (and it isn't choppy) the others are hidden, but still moving, right?

Comment: I am slightly confused, did this solve your issue? If not, if you want invisible objects to move to a specific point, don't animate it, Just do CGPointMake.

Comment: I don't want the invisible ones to move. No, that didn't solve my issue. My issue is that when I animate 5 squares, the animation is choppy. Forget about the hidden thing, it's not important

Comment: Do you know if the invisible ones are moving or not?

Comment: They are; I realized that memory is indeed the problem. self.view was actually removing the subviews of the squares I wanted hidden, their hidden values were not being changed. That is the reason for the improved performance. But how can I improve the efficiency of the animation with 5 squares moving? Is there a way? Or do I just have to live with not-optimal speed

Comment: There is most certainly a way to fix this. So just to be clear the invisible ones are moving but you do NOT want them to be moving?
Maybe once the buttons are invisible delete the UIView animation associated with them and see if that will help. Also try build and analyze for anything you might have missed!

Comment: Also if this is a game, I recommend you go with Cocos2D because that is made for things like this.

Comment: Yes, this is a game, but it has come out just how I wanted until this the way I have been doing it. No; the invisible ones are NOT moving because they have been removed from their superviews; they don't exist anymore. The problem does not occur when those are removed, it occurs when all five squares are present. When all five are present, the animation sliding the square across the screen is choppy.

Comment: Hmm that is odd. Did you try Core Animation?

Comment: No I didn't; what exactly would be the syntax for moving an object from CGPoint 'a' to CGPoint 'b' with in 'duration' time? And CoreAnimation.h is imported by importing QuartzCore.h, correct?

Comment: yes i believe so. There are some tutorials on the web showing how to do Core Animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that can cause this. It always comes down to how complex the content is. Also, simulator can be really bad about handling animation, so be sure you are testing on real hardware.

Are there large images on the buttons?  Are the buttons casting shadows?  Those things can slow it down.

Also- use block based animation. Not the old begin-commit methods.

Comment: Alright, I'll change them to block. But no, they have no shadows or complex images; they are solid UIColors, and yes, I am testing on real hardware. The performance is actually much better on the simulator, which leads me to believe that the problem is memory (of which the computer has much more)

Comment: Using begin-commit instead of block doesn't actually hurt performance, right?

Comment: Never trust the simulator’s performance—its characteristics are totally different than those of a device. Your computer has more memory, yes, but it also has a much faster CPU and GPU.

Comment: Yeah, but this brings me back to my original problem. It seems that memory for sure is the problem. But how can I conserve memory in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it's slow, but have you tried nesting the thing differently?

```
if(!shouldMove)
    return;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"b" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationSpeed];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

for(UIButton* button in squareArray) {
    view.center = destPoint;
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

does (almost - the logic is a bit different in the `!shouldMove` case, but that's a different story) the same, but in a cleaner way.

Comment: While this does seem cleaner, it would move all of the squares to the same point, which kinda defeats the purpose of having multiple squares :D

Comment: The moving part is equivalent. The code you showed does the same.

Comment: Oh, sorry! In my code I didn't show that I get a different random point for _each_ UIButton; I didn't think it was relevant. But yes, you're right, this code is equivalent to the code I posted. Sorry!